# SQLite insert from an activity android/java

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I'm using an activity to create an insert statment in my SQLite database, and I got a problem:

The table creating statement:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_QUESTION =
        "CREATE TABLE  " + TABLE_QUESTION + "("
                + KEY_ID_QUESTION + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_QUESTION + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_PROFIL_CIBLE + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_PROFIL_WAITEDANSWER + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_REGLE + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_PLANACT + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_THEME + " TEXT"
                + ")";
```

In my activity, I've made a function to insert the data:

```
public void createquestion( String question, String profile, String regle, String plan, String theme) {

                long id;

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                String questM = theme.concat(" - "+question);
                values.put(ModelHelper.KEY_QUESTION, questM);
                values.put(ModelHelper.KEY_PROFIL_CIBLE, profile);
                values.put(ModelHelper.KEY_REGLE, regle);
                values.put(ModelHelper.KEY_PLANACT, plan);
                values.put(ModelHelper.KEY_THEME, theme);


               long sql =  db.insert(ModelHelper.TABLE_QUESTION,null,values);
                //db.execSQL( sql);
            }
```

I've tried using another method by typing an sql statment like that:

```
 final String sql= ("INSERT INTO " +ModelHelper.TABLE_QUESTION+ "( '+ModelHelper.KEY_QUESTION+ ', ' +ModelHelper.KEY_PROFIL_CIBLE+ ', ' +ModelHelper.KEY_REGLE+ ',' +ModelHelper.KEY_PLANACT+ ', ' +ModelHelper.KEY_THEME+') VALUES  (' +questM+ ', ' +profile+ ', ' +regle+ ' ,' +plan+ ',' +theme ')");
```

db.execSQL( sql);

but it doesn't work neither, I have this error while clicking the button:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues)' on a null object reference

Can anyone help please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Your `db` is null.

Comment: You're right, I spent a lot of time correcting my SQL stat but I didn't saw my sqlhelper. thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't call db.insert(...) from your main thread, e.g. an activity. Use an AsynTask https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html to perform Database queries.